# Changing Fonts Size in Matlab Plots

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to change Font Size for `xlabel`, `ylabel`, axis size, legend font size a.k.a everything at once, is this possible? By default, font is Helvetica 10.

Is there way to change this?

I want to use 'FontSize',14, for **x** or **y** labels.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Jonas's answer is good, but I had to modify it slightly to get *every* piece of text on the screen to change:

```
set(gca,'FontSize',30,'fontWeight','bold')

set(findall(gcf,'type','text'),'FontSize',30,'fontWeight','bold')
```

Comment: How would one modify this to include the font type for the numbers on the axes?

Answer (score 51):

If you want to change font size for all the text in a figure, you can use `findall` to find all text handles, after which it's easy:

```
figureHandle = gcf;
%# make all text in the figure to size 14 and bold
set(findall(figureHandle,'type','text'),'fontSize',14,'fontWeight','bold')
```

Comment: See [answer by @sergeyf](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11439487/674976) below for changing the axis label font as well.

Answer (score 45):

It's possible to change default fonts, both for the axes and for other text, by adding the following lines to the `startup.m` file.

```
% Change default axes fonts.
set(0,'DefaultAxesFontName', 'Times New Roman')
set(0,'DefaultAxesFontSize', 14)

% Change default text fonts.
set(0,'DefaultTextFontname', 'Times New Roman')
set(0,'DefaultTextFontSize', 14)
```

If you don't know if you have a `startup.m` file, run

```
which startup
```

to find its location. If Matlab says there isn't one, run

```
userpath
```

to know where it should be placed.

Answer (score 9):

If anyone was wondering how to change the font sizes without messing around with the **Matlab default fonts**, and change *every* font in a figure, I found [this thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/173115) where suggests this:

`set(findall(fig, '-property', 'FontSize'), 'FontSize', 10, 'fontWeight', 'bold')`

[`findall`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findall.html) is a pretty handy command and in the case above it really finds all the children who have a `'FontSize'` property: *axes lables, axes titles, pushbuttons*, etc.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

To change the title font size, use the following example

```
title('mytitle','FontSize',12);
```

to the change the graph axes label font size, do the following

```
axes('FontSize',24);
```

Answer (score 5):

Jonas's answer does not change the font size of the axes. 
Sergeyf's answer does not work when there are multiple subplots.

Here is a modification of their answers that works for me when I have multiple subplots:

```
set(findall(gcf,'type','axes'),'fontsize',30)
set(findall(gcf,'type','text'),'fontSize',30)
```

Answer (score 4):

To change the default property for your entire MATLAB session, see the documentation on [how default properties are handled](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f7-21465.html).

As an example:

```
set(0,'DefaultAxesFontSize',22)
x=1:200; y=sin(x);
plot(x,y)
title('hello'); xlabel('x'); ylabel('sin(x)')
```