# How to bold legend and axis in 3d scatter plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab-figure, scatter-plot

I have one question. How to bold legend and axis in 3d scatter plot in Matlab?
Anyone can help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Run this after the figure is created, it sets all text elements of the current figure to bold:

```
set(findall(gcf,'type','text'), 'FontWeight','bold')
```

It is not 3D scatter specific and is answered here as well: [Changing Fonts in Matlab Plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934468/changing-fonts-in-matlab-plots)