# MATLAB uses wrong font and spacing in figure titles

Tags: matlab, fonts, figure

I am running OpenSuse Leap 42.2 and have just recently noticed, that the titles of my MATLAB figures look weird:

[image]

As you can see, the spacing is strange and I also have a different font in mind. Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: I think it should be something with `set(gca,'FontSize',30,'FontName', Cambria)' for ex. for earlier than 2014 releases ( I think) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934468/changing-fonts-in-matlab-plots

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on linux. What you can do is to set the font for every figure manually to a default matlab font or write a script which does it for you.

Comment: it can be done globally if you access the object handles of your graphics. check axes properties

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that happens (missing font in OpenSuse?), but you can set the default figure font globally:

```
set(0, 'DefaultAxesFontName','Cambria');
```

Include this in your [`startup.m`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html) for convenience.